# Accessing classes from libraries packaged in a jar

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I have developed a plugin for an application.  This plugin includes several libraries

When the plugin is called from the application I get a:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/media/imageioimpl/plugins/tiff/TIFFImageWriterSpi
```

I have confirmed that this class has been packaged with the plugin jar so  I am guessing that I need to use some sort of classloader in the plugin jar to access this class - but not sure how to.  Any help or re-direction appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let the application know where the plugin jars are located so that it can load the required classes at run time. You can do that by specifying the Class-Path entry ,that refers to the plugin jars, in the META-INF/MANIFEST file of your application jar.

```
Class-Path: plugin-jar-name1 plugin-jar-name2
```

Comment: Thank you - I am using Maven - should I add this with <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>?

Comment: Yes , that shoulld do

Comment: Yes, that add the path however this is in a plugin jar that is called by the main application and it still seems to be having issues - is it possible that the classpath in the manifest is only relevant if there is a main class in the jar?

Comment: I am assuming you are facing the issue when your application tries to load the plugin classes ,  in which case you need to update the application jar manifest with the Class-Path entry pointing to the plugin jars. To anwer  your question Class-Path is looked up by JVM/Classloader when a class tries to load another class from another jar.

Comment: I tried updating the plugin manifest with the classpath - but you are suggesting that the application manifest needs to know the classpath of the plugin dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `com.sun.media:jai_imageio:1.1` dependency into your `pom.xml`. you can find dependency belwo:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai_imageio</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

if your are using simple project you need to download `jai_imageio.jar` jar file from below link and put into `lib` directory and add into build path:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjaiimageiojar.htm